# How do I catch a java.net.ConnectException caused by Connection refused?

Tags: java, network-programming

I can't find a way to distinguish between different causes of ConnectExceptions in a reliable way (i.e. something other than inspecting the message string). I'm specifically interested in detecting a ConnectException caused by ECONNREFUSED as a terminating condition for retry logic.

Comment: In the javadoc there seems to be no way to get more information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ConnectException.html

Comment: can you please post your code (SSCCE)

Comment: Yes there seems to be no way other than relying on the message but why not use that meessage value for terminating retry conditon?

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already observed the message values changing between different VM implementations.

Comment: You shouldn't be retrying at all. TCP will already do some retries, that's why there is a minute or so timeout. The only time it doesn't do that is when an incoming RST is received, which is, err, connection refused. So in all possible cases it is incorrect to retry.

Comment: The retry logic is at the application level. For example, the network goes down for some time and I try to reconnect to a service that may no longer be available (i.e. an active connection refusal, not a timeout). However, I believe I will move the retry logic to a higher level in order to avoid this issue. Thanks for making me reevaluate my strategy.